# How to scroll in jQuery with an animation?

Tags: javascript

I want to scroll my page 1750px from the top with an animation. I tried the following and it doesn't work.

```
$('#trailer').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    //$(window).scrollTop(1750); // I want to animate this.
    $(window).animate(
        {top: 1750},
        200);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `scrollTop` instead of top and you have to call animate on the `body` (or both `html` and `body` depending on the browser):

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: 1750
}, 200);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hp72ht6/)